# How would you control transaction with Spring & Hibernate.

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I was asked this question during an interiew process a few week's back. I was not sure what to talk about. Do we need to talk about Session or Lazy loading/eager loading or Transaction manager or optimistic locking and pessimistic locking.

Comment: Talk about `@Transactional` annotation, what `propagation` does,
when does the transaction `rollback` ..

Comment: They asked me to answer with different scenarios. Could you give me a clue of what scenario and what are the things you would cover in the answer

Comment: Why this question was annotated duplicate? It's a good question. I suggest you to take a look at Spring Data docs

Answer (score 1):

Use `@Transactional` annotation at service base class.Use rollback conditions as when Exception thrown.

Comment: But they asked me to talk about control transaction with spring and hibernate. what are the things that i need to cover.

Comment: @Transactional annotation is spring annotation only, so when you use it you are using spring .You will need to define a particular platform transactionmanager as well like below<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" 
    p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory">
  </bean>